# mod_wsgi Apache error with django app

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, rhel6

I have a django (1.7) app that works pretty well on a Centos7 server. Now i moving to production server RHEL 6 and still have some issues.

The problem is the mod_wsgi.

The server config:

- RHEL6
- Apache 2.2
- Django 1.7
- Python 2.6

the apache error log

```
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=12827): Target WSGI script '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=12827): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=12827): Target WSGI script '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=12827): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Feb 20 11:18:39 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

the rest of the important files

**flweb.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess localhost python-path=/home/evtdb/FLWeb:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup localhost

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>

        <Directory /home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb>
        <Files wsgi.py>

                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Files>
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py**

```
"""
WSGI config for FLWeb project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "FLWeb.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**ldd modules/mod_wsgi.so**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6afff000)
    libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0x00007fd69fc02000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd69f9e5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd69f7e0000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fd69f5dd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd69f359000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd69efc4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000330aa00000)
```

I thought that a problem could be that mod_wsgi seems compiled with lib64, so I changed the python path on the flweb.conf to lib64 but it didn't worked

**EDIT:**
I realize the server has python 2.7 in /user/local/lib and that is the python version where django is installed. I changed the path in the conf file, but now I guess I need to rebuild the mod_wsgi

**EDIT2:**
Trying to rebuild mod_wsgi, have this problem

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

according to https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues is a conflict between python that was compiled to 32 bit and mod_wsgi to 64

Comment: `print sys.path` does django exist?

Comment: I haven't realized there was another python version installed  (made an EDIT)

Comment: `python -c 'import django; print django.__file__'` I'm not convinced your path is setup correctly. The python it's linked against doesn't matter, you can still provide an alternate interpreter to run the script (say a virtualenv).

Comment: as said in the edit, django is installed on python2.7 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc
).
 The problem now is that mod_wsgi is compiled with python2.6.  I'm trying to recompile mod_wsgi but I have some problems Mixing 32 Bit And 64 Bit Packages

Comment: Finally I rebuild python and mod_wsgi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681398/re-building-python-and-mod-wsgi?lq=1